# How to force content in NEXT UI navbar to the edges making full header?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

[image]

While using NEXT JS I'm trying to test the NEXT UI components in the examples on [NEXT UI web site](https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar) so I started with the `navbar` everything is ok but how to move its contents to the edges? why it's in the middle with like sort of padding or margin?

My navbar component copied same as in the site to a component file and executed directly like this in page.tsx

```
   <header>
      <Nav />  <-- the navbar file no fancy work
    </header>
```

I tried to remove padding, margin, use flex justify around apply things on `header` apply on `navbare` apply on `navbarcontent` however nothing works!

so any idea how to force them to occupies all that space making a full header ?

Comment: Hi. Could you please povide the relevant code + styles? It's nearly impossible to answer your question without seeing what you're actually doing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to do so because I didn't want answers to focus on code or workarounds as the code is correct, but I knew that there was a misunderstanding concept while using NEXTU somewhere which is clearly descripted in the answer below which is perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respected Sir,

The reasons why content is not moving to the edge is **Width of Navbar** !

Default is `lg`

They have provided [props](https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar#api) (scroll down to API section in bottom) which contains `maxWidth` property & it has valid values :

`sm | md | lg | xl | 2xl | full`

By default it's `lg`

You may pass full to get desired result.

```
<Navbar maxWidth={'full'}>
```